# How can I forward internet access from one modem to another?

Tags: internet, modem, forwarding

Let's suppose we have modem A connected to computer 1 and modem B connected to computer 2.

Let's assume that we have a modem A with full internet access and another modem B with only access to a couple of websites + telnet\web access to the first modem A. So, is it possible to forward full internet access from modem A to the other modem B and both of them still be connected to internet?

- Modem A and modem B are in the same ip range.
- Administrator access in available for both modems.

Comment: If your workplace doesn't allow facebook, just deal with it! :) kidding. Can you provide more information to see if there is an easier workaround to your issue?

Comment: thanks :d, well there are two adsl modems, tp-link 8811 and static ip address is available. any other information ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to run a proxy, like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), on a machine that has the modem that permits access to all sites as its default gateway. Machines that use the other modem can simply configure their browsers (or OSes, or applications, or whatever) to use that machine as a proxy.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i only have access to modem via telnet and web configuration and i can't install squid on it. what about routing section in modem ?

Comment: As I said, run it "on a machine that has the modem that permits access to all sites as its default gateway".